# Debugging Silverlight Applications

Tags: silverlight, debugging

As hard as I try, I cannot get my silverlight app to stop on break points. I've tried both in and out of browser debugging.

Steps I've done:

1. Repeatedly cleared my internet
   cache.
2. Made sure Silverlight
   debugging is enabled in my test web
   application.
3. Made sure symbols are
   loaded by placing a reference to the
   silverlight app in my test web
   application. (I had the hollow red
   dot problem, but this fixed it)
4. Restarted visual studio and the ASP.NET Development Server
5. Made sure I was attached to the right process by manually attaching to either sllauncher or the browser hosting the silverlight app.
6. Ensured that the xap file is being updated in the ClientBin directory after rebuilds.
7. Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution multiple times.

From my searches, I've found that debugging issues are usually caused by one of the above, but nothing seems to work. It looks like I'm debugging, but the application never breaks. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Are you sure that the lines of code with the breakpoints are being executed?

Comment: I have a few breakpoints set that should be executed no matter what: in MainPage() and in two events that are fired when my StoryBoard ends. I would assume that sometimes the events or timer callbacks might not fire because they're on another thread, but I'd assume anything set in MainPage would.

Comment: Was the solution below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties of the Web Application / Site.  In Visual Studio, Right Click --> Properties.  Click the 'Web' tab on the lower left.  On the bottom under the 'Debuggers' section, ensure that Silverlight is Checked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you use IE for application or other browser? Be sure that you use an IE.